# Leaflet map in Shiny not rendering when zoomed in; remains static

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

As stated, I'm using shiny dashboard. Leaflet map is not rendering when zoomed in. Here's the code. It's plotting the marker on the given lat,long. When zoomed in, its not working. And appears to be static and no rendering is done when zoomed in. Help is needed as soon as possible.

server.R

```
 mapPlot <- function(searchTerm, maxTweets, lang, lat, long, rad){


    mapTweets <- searchTwitter(searchString =  searchTerm, n = maxTweets, lang = "en", geocode = paste(lat,long,paste0(rad, "mi"),sep=","))

    mapTweets.df <- twListToDF(mapTweets)

    return(mapTweets.df)
  }

  entity13 <- eventReactive(input$mapit,{

    progress <- shiny::Progress$new(session, min=1, max=15)
    on.exit(progress$close())

    progress$set(message = 'Rendering the leaflet map to visualize')

    for (i in 1:15) {
      progress$set(value = i)
      Sys.sleep(0.5)
    }

    print("Calling..")
    entity13 <- mapPlot(input$k, input$n, lang = "en", input$lat, input$long, input$rad)
    entity13
      })


  output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({

    m <- leaflet(entity13()) %>% addTiles() %>%

    addMarkers(entity13()$longitude, entity13()$latitude, popup = entity13()$screenName) 

    m %>% setView(entity13()$longitude, entity13()$latitude, zoom = 4)

    m
})
```

ui.R
(just a snippet of code which is important)

```
    column(width = 9,
   box(width = NULL, solidHeader = TRUE,
     leafletOutput("mymap", height = 500)
             ))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's the `NA`s in your lat/long columns that's causing the issue. Try removing those before plotting - see my line in `output$mymap`. Note that twitter doesn't automatically include a geocode for all its tweets, sometimes they are blank/NA.

Here is an example that you can run (with your own `twitteR` authorisation keys etc).

---

Note that in your question you should make it reproducible so that someone can just copy & paste your code and it will run, without having to make significant edits or guesses as to what you mean

---

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(leaflet)
library(twitteR)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(column(width = 9,
                       box(width = NULL, solidHeader = TRUE,
                           leafletOutput("mymap", height = 500)
                       )))
)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  # consumerKey <- "...xxx..."
  # consumerSecret <- "...xxx..."
  # accessToken <- "...xxx..."
  # accessSecret <- "...xxx..."

  searchTerm <- "twitter"
  maxTweets <- 50
  lat <- -37.8278185
  long <- 144.9666907
  rad <- 100

  mapPlot <- function(searchTerm, maxTweets, lang, lat, long, rad){

    # setup_twitter_oauth(consumer_key = consumerKey, consumer_secret = consumerSecret,
    #                     access_token = accessToken, access_secret = accessSecret)

    mapTweets <- searchTwitteR(searchString =  searchTerm, 
                               n = maxTweets, 
                               lang = "en", 
                               geocode = paste(lat, long, paste0(rad, "mi"),sep=","))

    mapTweets.df <- twListToDF(mapTweets)

    return(mapTweets.df)
  }

  output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({

    entity13 <- mapPlot(searchTerm, maxTweets, lang = "en", lat, long, rad)
    ## Remove NAs
    entity13 <- entity13[!is.na(entity13$longitude), ]

    leaflet() %>% 
      addTiles() %>%
      addMarkers(data = entity13, lng = entity13$longitude, lat = entity13$latitude, popup = entity13$screenName) %>%
      setView(lng = long, lat = lat, zoom = 4)

  })
})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

---

To convince yourself of this, consider:

```
df <- structure(list(longitude = c("145.21366882", "144.97520704", 
NA, NA, "144.929263"), latitude = c("-37.951828", "-37.7963", 
NA, NA, "-37.78712")), .Names = c("longitude", "latitude"), row.names = c(1L, 
2L, 5L, 6L, 7L), class = "data.frame")

## rows 5 & 6 have NA
df
#      longitude   latitude
# 1 145.21366882 -37.951828
# 2 144.97520704   -37.7963
# 5         <NA>       <NA>
# 6         <NA>       <NA>
# 7   144.929263  -37.78712

lat <- -37.8278185
long <- 144.9666907

## plotting all rows - zoom doesn't work and only first two markers shown
leaflet(data = df) %>% 
  addTiles() %>%
  addMarkers(lng = ~longitude, lat = ~latitude) %>%
  setView(lng = long, lat = lat, zoom = 4)


## only include non-NA rows - works as desired
leaflet(data = df[c(1,2,5),]) %>% 
  addTiles() %>%
  addMarkers(lng = ~longitude, lat = ~latitude) %>%
  setView(lng = long, lat = lat, zoom = 4)
```

Comment: It works! Your effort in teaching me was great . I learnt one valuable lesson. Thank you!

Comment: I knew twitter search API returns some tweets with NA's. But it didn't strike that I should remove NA's from the returned results. Much grateful to you for your timely help  and I'll take your advice that I'll post the code in a reproducible manner!

Comment: @SolomonAathiRaj - you're welcome - glad I could help.